# pyignite - performance issue

Tags: python, ignite, apacheignite

I made a speed comparison of retrieving data from Apache Ignite using several methods.
All records are in one table, I did not use any WHERE condition, only a SELECT * FROM TABLE XYZ LIMIT 20000.

Test results are:

#### Apache Ignite

- Apache Ignite REST API -  0.52 seconds
- JDBC                   -  4    seconds
- Python pyignite        - 40    seconds !!!

pseudocode in Python using pyignite:

```
client = Client(username="ignite", password="pass", use_ssl=False)
client.connect('localhost', 10800)

cursor=client.sql('SELECT * FROM TABLE_XYZ LIMIT 20000')
for row in cursor:
    pass
```

After that I made a speed comparison of retrieving data from PostgreSQL using JDBC and psycopg2 Python package.
SQL select is same, SELECT * FROM TABLE XYZ LIMIT 20000

#### PostgreSQL

- JDBC                            -  3    seconds
- Python psycopg2 using fetchall  -  3    seconds
- Python psycopg2 using fetchone  -  4    seconds

pseudocode in Python using psycopg2:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database=DB_NAME,
            user=DB_USER,
            password=DB_PASS,
            host=DB_HOST,
            port=DB_PORT)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE_XYZ LIMIT 20000")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for data in rows:
    pass
```

I can conclude that the pyignite implementation has much worse performance compared to psycopg2 tests. The performance difference on PostgreSQL between Java JDBC and Python psycopg2 is negligible.
The performance difference on Apache Ignite between Java JDBC and Python pyignite is very big.

Please if someone can comment on the tests, did I do something wrong or are these results expected?
How can such large differences in execution times be explained?
Do you have any suggestions to get better results using pyignite?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit surprised that JDBC test is x8 times slower than REST. I suppose that might be related to the test itself, i.e. what and how do you measure.

If you have multiple nodes and your cache doesn't have backups on each node, check if you have [partitionAwareness](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/JDBC/jdbc-driver#partition-awareness) enabled and if not, consider turning it on.

As of pyignite, it's kind of expected because of the Python's internals. Most of the time waste happens on objects deserialization. I don't think there is something to do with that at the moment.

Instead, if you need SQL only, check if using [Ignite ODBC driver](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/ODBC/odbc-driver) + `pyodbc` will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for reply.

I made a mistake on the first test when I used the REST API.
The host from which I ran the tests and the network bandwidth were not the same.
I repeated the test and the results I got using Ignite REST API and JDBC are almost the same.

REST API - 1.7 seconds
JDBC     - 2   seconds

Regarding ODBC and pyodbc, I made a new test and SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 20000 is also around two seconds.

Best regards